# List of dictionaries to json file

Tags: python, json

I want to convert a list of dictionaries to one json file.
I´ve done it but in the wrong format.
I kind of did it but the file is missing some ',' and some '[]'

```
import re 
import json 

listadics = []
N=20
with open("processos.txt", "r") as fileoriginal:
    fileN = [next(fileoriginal) for x in range(N)]

for v in fileN: 
    lista = re.split(r'::|[ ]+[ ]+',v)
    dic = {}
    contador = 0 
    nome = 1 
    linha = 0 
    for elemento in lista: 
        if elemento != '\n' and elemento != '': 
            if contador == 0: 
                dic["numero processo"] = elemento
            elif contador == 1: 
                dic["data"] = elemento
            elif contador >= 2: 
                dic["nome(s)" + str(nome)] = elemento
                nome += 1
            contador += 1
    listadics.append(dic)
    
    with open("json.json", 'a') as file:
        file.write((json.dumps(dic, indent=4, sort_keys= False)))
```

Comment: You're writing multiple times to the file - build a list and write once, instead.

Comment: Right, that's exactly the problem.  Many people don't understand that a JSON file must be a single object or list.  You can't just concatenate multiple JSON documents together.

Comment: But how can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

I solve´d it:

```
import re 
import json 

listadics = []
N=20
with open("processos.txt", "r") as fileoriginal:
    fileN = [next(fileoriginal) for x in range(N)]

for v in fileN: 
    lista = re.split(r'::|[ ]+[ ]+',v)
    dic = {}
    contador = 0 
    nome = 1 
    linha = 0 
    for elemento in lista: 
        if elemento != '\n' and elemento != '': 
            if contador == 0: 
                dic["numero processo"] = elemento
            elif contador == 1: 
                dic["data"] = elemento
            elif contador >= 2: 
                dic["nome(s)" + str(nome)] = elemento
                nome += 1
            contador += 1
    listadics.append(dic)
    
with open("json.json", 'a') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(listadics, indent=4, sort_keys= False)))
```